# How to insert record to SharePoint List Multi Choice Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need help, my code right now is working but with a couple of issues, like for example I'm able to insert the record on the SharePoint List with no problem on the single line & choice field, but for the multi choice field I'm unable to stored the data on the List itself, it displays on the view but when you try to edit the item, the data isn't stored on the Item's Form.

This is my code:

```
function createListItem() {
        var devName = document.getElementById("devName").value;
        var gbsService = document.getElementById("gbsService").value;

        var selectedValues = '';      
            $("#techUsed :Selected").each(function(){
                selectedValues += $(this).val() + ",";
            });

            if(selectedValues.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                selectedValues = selectedValues.slice(0, -1); 
            }

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('SP URL');
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SP List Name');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', devName);
        oListItem.set_item('Technology_x0020_Used', selectedValues);
        oListItem.set_item('GBS_x0020_Service_x0020_Organiza', gbsService);

        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.load(oListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: For `selectedValues`, aren't you looking for a value from the choice field ( which will be a single value), adding `,` to it, then deleting it if you add it? Why even add it if you are going to delete it?

Is the issue that none of the data actually gets stored? Or just the `gbsService` (which I'm guessing is the multi-choice field)?

Comment: I'm just removing the last ",".

But I was able to obtain all the values from the multi-choice using jquery instead of js,like this: var techUsed = $('#techUsed').val(); Apparently, jquery works better on a SP environment instead of using the: document.getElementById("techUsed").value;

Regardless, thanks for everything I really appreciate you assistance.